# ldap_search(): Partial search results returned: Sizelimit exceeded retrieve only 1000 users

Tags: php, laravel, ldap

I use ladap to retrieve users from Active Directory and total users more than 1000 users. I got a warning like this:

> ldap_search(): Partial search results returned: Sizelimit exceeded

Does anyone have a solution for that error? Because I want to retrieve all users from AD to my database.

Answer (score 0):

Typically when [LDAP_SIZELIMIT_EXCEEDED](https://ldapwiki.com/wiki/LDAP_SIZELIMIT_EXCEEDED) this implies you have a size limit set on your client or on the LDAP server or when using Microsoft Active Directory where you could be running into a [MaxPageSize](https://ldapwiki.com/wiki/MaxPageSize) "Feature".